JDK 17 corretto & Spring 6.1 migration
I am upgrading an application in Open JDK 11 corretto with Spring 4.3 to JDK 17 corretto Spring 6.1
got the below exception:-
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/iRes_Booking_WS]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:683)
        ... 37 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpURI$Mutable can not implement org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpURI, because it is not an interface (org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpURI is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @5d5160e6)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2487)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:865)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1401)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1245)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.<clinit>(ContextHandler.java:140)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.config.JettyWebSocketServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(JettyWebSocketServletContainerInitializer.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4875)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 38 

expecting the web application to work as it was earlier [JDK 11 & Spring 4.3]

This would need a reproducible code, mostly with other dependencies involved in the project.

Judging from the error you are using incompatible Jetty libraries. When upgrading to Spring 6 you also need a newer Jetty (JakartaEE compatible not JavaEE).
